# UWP-APP Application Error on Release Build

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to create a simple UWP-APP.
However, I recently discovered some issues, but only while performing a Release Build.
When a debug build is performed, the UWP-APP works fine.

After I navigate to a specific Page, the App shows me the following Exception:

```
Exception error for 0x78612B20 (SharedLibrary.dll) in MNRC-APP.exe: 0xC7536E53
```

The Windows Event Logger displays the following Application Error:

```
Name of the corrupted application: linked.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, timestamp: 0x5ff86d3f
Name of the corrupted module: SharedLibrary.dll, version: 2.2.29512.0, timestamp: 0x5fad1a6e
Exception Code: 0xc7536e53
Error offset: 0x0000000000690556
ID of the faulty process: 0x5874
Start time of the faulty application: 0x01d6e75d22c7648e
Path of the faulty application: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\48791DKAPPS.MNRC-APP_1.1.26.0_x64__3s1a31dcph6dt\linked.exe
Path of the corrupted module: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.2.2_2.2.29512.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\SharedLibrary.dll
Report identifier: cd102ead-8404-4699-b0ff-caee357d162d
Full name of the corrupted package: 48791DKAPPS.MNRC-APP_1.1.26.0_x64__3s1a31dcph6dt
Application ID relative to the corrupted package: App
```

I'm just really confused at this point, due to the corrupted module being in a Framework folder.
Can anyone please help me fix this problem?

After adding the Application.UnhandledException Event in my App, I got the following Error:

```
Search source for "f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\CoreRT\src\System.Private.CoreLib\shared\System\Runtime\Intrinsics\X86\Sse42.PlatformNotSupported.cs". Checksum: SHA1 {64 24 11 c6 2 b2 e7 bf ee b8 5d f6 81 fe 83 ac 35 be 57 cd}
The file "f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\CoreRT\src\System.Private.CoreLib\shared\System\Runtime\Intrinsics\X86\Sse42.PlatformNotSupported.cs" does not exist.
"f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\CoreRT\src\System.Private.CoreLib\shared\System\Runtime\Intrinsics\X86\Sse42.PlatformNotSupported.cs" is searched in script document...
"f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\CoreRT\src\System.Private.CoreLib\shared\System\Runtime\Intrinsics\X86\Sse42.PlatformNotSupported.cs" is searched in projects.
The file was not found in a project.
Documents embedded in the symbol file are searched for.
An embedded document was not found.
The source file debugging settings for the active solution specify that the user is not prompted to search for the file: f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\CoreRT\src\System.Private.CoreLib\shared\System\Runtime\Intrinsics\X86\Sse42.PlatformNotSupported.cs.
The source file "f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\CoreRT\src\System.Private.CoreLib\shared\System\Runtime\Intrinsics\X86\Sse42.PlatformNotSupported.cs" was not found.
```

I figured out, how to perform a Build with the Compile with .NET Native tool chain option enabled.
However, I receive only the same error as usual:

```
Exception error for 0x78AFD898 (SharedLibrary.dll) in MNRC-APP.exe: 0xC7536E53
```

Can someone please explain to me what exactly this means, or what I can do about it.

Comment: It's hard to find where the issue happens exactly. Could you please try to handle the [Application.UnhandledException Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application.unhandledexception?view=winrt-19041) in your app to see if we could get more information about how the issue happened?

Comment: First of all thank you for your quick reply. 
I added the Application.UnhandledException Event in my App.
However, the Error is too long for an answer, so I added it in the entry post.

Comment: So what is the exception message and the exception code? Are they the same as the first log?  Another attempt is that please set your project in debug mode first. Then you could right-click your project, select `properties`, go to `Build` page, enable the `Compile with .NET Native tool chain` option. Run you app to see if VS could find the place where the issue happens.

Comment: When I activate the option "Compile with .NET Native tool chain", I get an error in XamlTypeInfo.g.cs (specific error info in the opening post).

The message and exception code is the same as in the first log.

Comment: "Sse42.PlatformNotSupported.cs" makes me thing about running on a CPU that doesn't have support for SSE 4.2. Do you target something other than plain old x86?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My Device supports SSE 4.2. In addition i only target x86. Any other idea or suggestion?

Comment: I figured out, how to build with the Compile with .NET Native tool chain enabled.
However, I receive the same error as usual (error mentioned in the entry post).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time, a lot of research and trial and error, I finally found the problem.
In my App, I used a .dll, which relied on [Threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/threading-async/). This resulted in the App crashing.
I simply worked around that, by using a .dll which does not use Threads.
Thanks for your all your help and suggestions.